# Sql Join to get values in two lists

Tags: sql-server

Microsoft SQL Server 2012

I have three scalar variables:

```
declare @ListA table (value int);
declare @ListB table (value int);
declare @InBoth table (value int);
```

I want to get a list of numbers that are in both lists.

```
insert into @InBoth 
   select value 
   from @ListA 
   inner join @ListB on @ListA.value = @ListB.value;
```

I get an error

> Must declare the scalar variable

for both `@ListA` and `@ListB` inside the `join` statement.

How do I get a list of numbers that are in both lists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `table variable` name as `alias` instead give `alias` name to the `table variable` and use the `alias` name to identify the columns

```
INSERT INTO @InBoth
SELECT A.value
FROM   @ListA A
       INNER JOIN @ListB B
               ON A.value = B.value;
```

or use `EXISTS` operator

```
INSERT INTO @InBoth
SELECT A.value
FROM   @ListA A
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   @ListB B
               WHERE  A.value = B.value)
```